# How to use Vue draggabale in Vue js 3

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, draggable, vuejs3

I'm trying to use Draggable in Vue js 3 but it shows me error:
`VueCompilerError: v-slot can only be used on components or <template> tags.`

Here is my code

```
 <draggable tag="transiton-group" name="slide" item-key="id" @start="drag=true" @end="drag=false" v-model="todos">
  <li #item="" v-for="(todo, index) in filteredTodos" :key="todo.id" class="todo-item">
    <input @click="toggleDone(todo)" class="js-tick" id="1610198328386" type="checkbox" :checked="todo.done">
    <span :class="{ done: todo.done }">{{ todo.task }}</span>
    <img @click="deleteTodo(index)" class="delete" width="15px" height="15px" src="~@/assets/icon-cross.svg" alt="cross">
  </li>
</draggable>
```

Also mt transition group is not working anymore after I replaced it with draggable

Comment: Did you install the [vue.draggable.next](https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next) version?

Comment: @Daedalus yes I did

Answer (score 0):

`#item=""` is a shorthand of `v-slot:item=""` which should be used only with component tag :

```
 <draggable #item="" ...>
  <li  ...
</draggable>
```

or template tag :

```
 <draggable  ...>
  <template #item="">
   <li ...
  </template>
</draggable>
```

Comment: the error is gone but now when I add todo it creates multiple todos not one

Comment: because you're looping through `li` with v-for